# How to push object inside an array while writing to a file in Node Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, fs

How to push object inside an array while writing to a file in Node Js?
I currently have the following working code

```
fs.appendFile("sample.json", JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2) + ",");
```

where data is an object, like

```
{
name:'abc',
age: 22,
city: 'LA'
}
```

Upon appending, which results the following

```
{
name:'abc',
age: 22,
city: 'LA'
},
{
name:'def',
age: 25,
city: 'MI'
},
```

I see 2 problems here.
1. The trailing comma at the end
2. The inability to form an array and push the object into it

Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: for the trailing comma, wouldn't be simpler to add the + "," at the beginning and perform a check the "first append" to not include it..

Comment: Probably you should try, without + sign and comma. When the next object pushed, it must be separated with comma automatically, I guess.

Answer (score 7):

Append will append your data to a file and here data is being treated as a string and all appends will be equal to concating string to another string.

Instead, here the file needs to be read first and converted to a data-structure for this example it can be an array of objects and convert that data-structure to string and write it to file.

To write to the file

```
fs.writeFileSync('sample.json', JSON.stringify([data], null, 2));
```

> sample.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 22,
    "city": "LA"
  }
]
```

Read from file

```
const fileData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('sample.json'))
fileData.push(newData)
```

Write the new data appended to previous into file

```
fs.writeFileSync('sample.json', JSON.stringify(fileData, null, 2));
```

> sample.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 22,
    "city": "LA"
  },
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 22,
    "city": "LA"
  }
]
```